# Received Memory Warning when MapView is loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, mkmapview

I am working on a project in which I have a ViewController with **MapView** in it.

Now this page is loaded and dismissed several times.

What I first implemented was, I added MapView in xib and and then every time this page loaded then live bites used to increase by 10mb.

**Solution1**

Then after doing research for this issue what I found was to use single object for **MKMapView** and define it in **AppDelegate** and use it all the time.

I tried this and it decreased the memory usage to some extent but again after sometime the app got crashed due to **Received Memory Warning**.

Now if I again launch the app after crash, then it used to crash on the very first time on opening the MapView page, **the live bites at this time were around 11mb only**.

> This is the code to add mapview in AppDelegate

```
 mapView=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 450)]; 

[self.window addSubview:mapView]; 

mapView.delegate=self; 

mapView.hidden=YES;
```

> This was the code which I used to load Mapview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    latittude=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LATITUDE"] floatValue];
    longitude=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LONGITUDE"] floatValue];

    APPDELEGATE.mapView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 140, 320, 290);

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    APPDELEGATE.mapView.hidden=NO;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude  = latittude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    Annotation *a;
    a=[[Annotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:location];
    [APPDELEGATE.mapView addAnnotation:a ];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    APPDELEGATE.mapView.hidden=YES;
}
```

**Solution2**

Second solution I found was to change MapView type when view disappears.

**So I changed its type, changed its delegate to nil and removed from superview on ViewWillDisappear.**

Even this didn't made any difference.

Any idea how can I overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The memoryWarning itself isn't a problem, it tells you that system has low memory.
Can you show the viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear (and didAppear) and viewWillDisappear (and willDisappear)?

Comment: @MarcoPace I have edit my question. Please look for all the methods mentioned by you.

Comment: set mapview = nil in viewWillDisAppear

Comment: @karthika I have tried this as well it decreased the memory usage to some extent but some amount of memory still remains there and hence keeps on incresing on opening the page again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a MapView in the app delegate seems like a bit of a strange solution. I'd go back to having it contained in a single controller as you did originally.

> What I first implemented was, I added MapView in xib and and then
>   every time this page loaded then live bites used to increase by 10mb.

This is your problem and it looks like a memory leak. The app size shouldn't increase if you are handling your objects / memory correctly. Make sure you are using arc and check you are setting any required objects (e.g NSTimers, NSNotifications) to nil in the viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: Forget all of this my coding. Just try to make the simple demo with one view which includes map, not any extra coding. Check the allocation memory of this project. If also faces the same issue.